# What does ぶつまね (ぶつ真似?) mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm just wondering what does the word "ぶつまね" (or also ぶつ真似 as turned up by a google search) mean? I tried guessing from the context of some 10 example sentences but still can't come up with the meaning of the word.

My original sentence is this one:

> 「先輩っ。ひっかけ問題はひどいです」ぶつまねをするテトラちゃん。

The girl in question is tricked into answering "yes" to a question of whether a given calculation is correct. The answer she had been given is almost right except for a single number in it.

Thank you in advance.

Example sentences
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/examples/jn2/193338/m0u/

Comment: [ぶつ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/193341/m0u/%E3%81%B6%E3%81%A4/) 真似 ≒ たたくフリ??

Comment: That sentence doesn't appear to contain the word you're asking about...  What was the sentence it appeared in?

Comment: Oh, I forgot the relevant part in my own example. It's
actually 
「先輩っ。ひっかけ問題はひどいです」ぶつまねをするテトラちゃん。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is two words ---「ぶつ」 + 「まね/真似」

"Verb + まね" = "pretending to 'Verb'"

ぶつ means "to hit", "to punch", etc.

Thus, 「ぶつまね」 means "(giving) a mock punch"

If, indeed, 「ぶつまね」 were one word as you claim, I would have no idea what that could  mean (and I am a native speaker.)

Comment: なるほど。言われるとそうですね…ありがとうございます！
なんで最初その分け方をしなかったんだろう、私。（笑）